# How to Set IP to Static with Powershell and Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an Azure Dev Test Lab that I am deploying to Azure via Power Shell. I am able to deploy the ARM templates and join to the test domain (not Azure AD) with no issues. The next step I would like to do is to set the IP to static. I can think of 3 ways to possibly do this. Either figure out the IP structure beforehand and deploy it with those settings. Let the DHCP assign the settings and try to problematically set them from Dynamic to Static using Powershell DSC. Or some type of preferred lease from the DHCP. These labs are meant to be stood up and torn down ad hoc. The IPs are internal and not Public. It is possible for me to know the IPs before hand. Could someone make a recommendation on what would make the most sense to pursue?

Comment: Azure configuration questions are off-topic and better suited on Serverfault - unless there's a programming question.

Comment: Updated to include IP info. It is internal, not public,

Comment: 2 Out of three options require powershell scripting, so I feel this is more suited for here. I will post of serverfault also.

Comment: you can just use ARM Templates for that, check my answer. also, this is a perfectly valid question, its not asking how to configure a server, its asking how to automate the deployment @vonPryz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several ways of looking at it, first of all, you can define ip at deployment time, by setting it to static, instead of dynamic:

```
{
"name": "xxx",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
"apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
"location": "loc",
"properties": {
  "ipConfigurations": [
    {
      "name": "ipconfig1",
      "properties": {
        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "privateIPAddress": "ipgoeshere",
        "subnet": {
          "id": "subnetgoeshere"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but this method is only valid if you know the available IP addresses beforehand and you will have to look those up and pass to the template.

Another way of doing this is créating NIC as dynamic, getting its IP address and setting it to static. All can be done with an ARM Template. The example is a bit too much to paste here, you can check it [here](https://github.com/robotechredmond/301-sql-alwayson-md/blob/master/nestedtemplates/deploy-sql-cluster.json). look for deployments called: `"[concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'),'setStaticIp')]"`, and `"[concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'),copyIndex(1),'-primaryIp')]",` and their corresponding templates: [getip](https://github.com/robotechredmond/301-sql-alwayson-md/blob/master/nestedtemplates/getIpAddress.json) and [setip](https://github.com/robotechredmond/301-sql-alwayson-md/blob/master/nestedtemplates/setNicStaticIp.json)

You can do pretty much the same with powershell, I dont have a script Handy, but the logic is the same, deploy > getip > setip